# How does VS2010 Configure Service Reference deal with localhost?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I go and setup a service reference to something like

```
http://localhost/myService/test.svc
```

However, it apparently does some magic and in the *.disco file (and elsewhere) it ends up with

```
http://mymachine.mydomain.com/myService/test.svc
```

I'm trying to understand why this happens.

Update:  It seems they're trying to "help" but the IDE continues to give you the impression that you're connecting to localhost.  In 99.9% of cases, it probably works out fine.  In my case, I'm connecting to a service which checks its licenses against the domain name.  Running against "localhost" is to be used for dev and test purposes.

The relevant portion of the *.config file ends up like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mymachine.mydomain.com/myService/test.svc/Account"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAccount"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IAccount"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IAccount">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How would a remote client be able to call `localhost` ? WCF does the right thing - it replaces the locally available thing (localhost) with something that could potentially be called from some other machine. What is bothering you about this??

Comment: I've got a piece of software which runs it licensing and activation by inspecting the domain name used to access the service.  By using "localhost" you can use it in development mode without having to burn one of your activations.  The big bother is the behavior of this activation scheme.

Comment: OK, that's a valid reason - hmm.... I vaguely remember reading about something new in WCF 4 that might allow you to control and influence that behavior - can't find a reference right now - let me do some digital digging......

Comment: I had a similar issue and found this. Very interesting situation. +1 for a good question.  I'm surprised I'm the first upvote.